# Android: интеграция с соц. сетями

Tags: android, java

Как правильно интегрировать своё приложение/игру с социальными сетями так, чтобы не забивать проект кучей ненужного кода?

Интересуют ВК, Facebook и Twitter. Единственная цель - замещение записи на стене. Более ничего не требуется.

Возможно ли это сделать уже через установленные на устройство приложения? Например, если это ВК, то через оф. приложение или Kate Mobile?

Или же придётся использовать сторонние библиотеки? Если да - то какие посоветуете?

Comment: У социальных сетей (кроме твиттера) есть свои СДК для работы с ними. Используйте эти СДК. Для твиттера существуют неофициальные СДК\библиотеки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужно совсем просто, то используйте это:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType(«text/plain»); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "_SUBJECT_");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "_BODY_");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.app_name)));
```

Откроется стандартный диалог шаринга, который покажет все возможные варианты шаринга. Т.е. если у юзера установлекн вк\фб клиенты то они там будут. Иначе использовать СДК.